# IE 7 Word-wrap bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem with my html page. I have text that is word-wrapping in a defined width box. It looks great in of course Firefox and IE8. However, when checking its backwards compatibility I found that the word-wrapping causes a random spacing issue where one line of text seems as if it has a margin-top specified on it.

Anyone ran into this issue before?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's inside a multi-line label.

Comment: Please post a code snippet that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any line-height:XXpx; in your css (if not add one)